# How can I improve my question when a comment was not supplied with a downvote?

Tags: discussion

meta about: [Who is the target group for Apple Arcade (subscription gaming service)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/390631/who-is-the-target-group-for-apple-arcade-subscription-gaming-service)

I am looking for very simple games (and platforms) that are graphically reasonably good and playable for older people. The reaction and attention decreases with increasing age.

Then I came across Apple Arcade and wondered if it could be something.

But my question got downvote(s), without a comment what I can improve. In other communities this is not usual, but apparently other rules apply here. I myself am not a gamer and new here in this community.

Comment: The problem is that apple Arqade is a very wide service, with a bunch of games that could be for different target groups. Game by game you might have an answer, but most groups could probably find a game within the subscription that is for them. But yeah, at the end of the day, the plus/minus vote is a power that most users have, and they are not required to comment if they downvote. Might just be that they didn't like your question.

Answer (score 7):

First, let me recommend going through the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).  Also, feel free to go through some of the articles in the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help), such as [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Basically, Arqade is a Q&A site for questions related to playing games, but there are some restrictions.  For example, asking for a list of games meeting a certain criteria is off-topic.

As for the specific question you linked, I'd recommend rewording it.  As it stands, it comes across as if you want to ask Apple who they are targeting for their gaming service.  This would fall under the off-topic category for developer intent, as we are not Apple and can't definitively answer that.

A better wording would be something like "Is Apple Arcade accessible for older (60+) non-gamers".  If you have a specific group in mind, focus your question on if Apple Arcade would work for their specific needs.  The goal is to have a question that is answerable by the users of a game/service, not the creators of it.

As an aside, you can always ask in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) for game recommendations or other suggestions.

Comment: I like this answer - except for _maybe_ the "Is Apple Arcade accessible for older (60+) non-gamers" part - that may draw opinionated answers only, but it is an improvement.  When I first saw the post, I immediately thought _this is a developer intent_ question myself.

Comment: @TimmyJim I agree, which is why I think having a specific group in mind could be helpful.  Like if you are specifically worried about people with poor eyesight, you could ask specifically about readability and what-not.

Comment: @TimmyJim An example of that exact sort of question was well received here: [How accessible is ring fit adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364699/how-accessible-is-ring-fit-adventure)

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't.

---

That being said, votes on Stack Exchange sites are indicative of one thing, and one thing only; how the community at large feels about the quality of posts. To quote the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) page:

> Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.

The voting system is unfortunately, highly subjective. While I may find your question intriguing, and the goal admirable, others might not and they could reflect that by voting. This means that votes can be given without comments, simply because a user did or didn't like the question.

The downvote in particular has a negative impact to author mentality, but that thought process shifts with more exposure to the site. The likely cause of your downvote was, as @Batphobia pointed out, that your post is currently off-topic because it *appears* to be asking about developer intent. Specifically, the opening statement:

> I wonder who the target audience of Apple Arcade on AppleTV is.

The problem is, this is something that is typically highly unknown to the gaming community at large. As such, it leads to opinionated answers, and, subsequently, misleading information for future readers.

Even rephrasing your question to ask which *genres* of games would be best for users in specific age groups would be considered off-topic; simply because, the answers would likely be opinionated instead of being backed by scientific analysis.

Also note that your post lacks clarity in that many questions can be inferred from it. For example, [a comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/390631/who-is-the-target-group-for-apple-arcade-subscription-gaming-service#comment549177_390631) already points out three:

> ...what the target audience is, whether it's suitable for seniors, and which games would be fun for seniors...

Additionally, I *personally*, *partially* disagree with @Batphobia's answer where they state:

> If you have a specific group in mind, focus your question on if Apple Arcade would work for their specific needs.

Simply because of the statement that follows immediately after:

> The goal is to have a question that is answerable by the users of a game/service, not the creators of it.

I believe that simply refocusing to a specific age group's needs would still lead to opinionated answers, and as such would still have a high probability of being downvoted and closed. Instead, I'd *refocus* to a specific age group (hence the partial disagreement), and then *broaden*, yet *refine* by asking for titles that belong to genres *known* to meet the needs of that age group.

A good way to phrase this would be something like:

> According to Awesome Source, the reaction times and attention spans of human beings decrease as age increases:
>
> > Some quote about the aforementioned information from Awesome Source to support your claim.
>
> This is because of X, Y, and maybe Z:
>
> > Some additional quote summarizing why X, Y and Z are problems.
>
> I'm trying to find games that wouldn't rely on X, would minimize the impact of Y, and still be enjoyable. During my research, I found that the A, B and C genres tend to meet these requirements, but I'm having trouble finding titles available through Apple Arcade (for whatever that reasoning is). What are the top 5 titles in these genres available through Apple Arcade (as of today)?

Notice how by the end of this question, if you have answered nearly everything in the question during your research phase, you're likely to no longer have a question at all because the top 5 titles for specific genres in Apple Arqade is easy information to find.

That should be the goal of a question author, but, this is often not the case. A good question is one that:

- Supplies potential answerers with *all* of the required prerequisites (if any).
- Clearly articulates a question about a problem.
- Ensures that no additional questions can be inferred.
- Demonstrates an effort to answer the question yourself.

There are more bullet points for other users, but that's often my checklist before I vote.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Agree with the "lead to opinionated answers" part.

Comment: I also "personally, partially disagree with @Batphobia", bust mostly because I dislike the concept of questions being judged by answers.  This topic is a bit of an edge case, but as a best chance, the less you are looking for a list and the more specific you are asking about, the better.  Also worth noting that being subjective is not necessarily cause for off-topic.  [This meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243200/225764) gives general advice, but I think gaming "experts" can have valuable opinions, such as how to counter certain builds.